# How to draw polygon on angular google maps using @agm-core?

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

In my application, I use Angular Google Maps (AGM) to build a map. How can I draw a polygon on it? I followed the solution described in https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-polygon but some directives are missing. How can I enable the drawing manager on the AGM map and draw polygons like in the example?

This is the import in the app.module:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'key',      
      language: localStorage && localStorage.defaultLang || 'el',
      libraries: ['places', 'drawing', 'geometry']
    })
```

Comment: Solved at: [how-to-get-paths-of-agm-polygon-when-it-is-edited-and-dragged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131170/how-to-get-paths-of-agm-polygon-when-it-is-edited-and-dragged/55124994#55124994)

Comment: Solved at: [how-to-get-paths-of-agm-polygon-when-it-is-edited-and-dragged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131170/how-to-get-paths-of-agm-polygon-when-it-is-edited-and-dragged/55124994#55124994)

Comment: Integrating agm with angular has got me stuck many times. I found it easier to get it using the Google Maps API. Find two articles on Google Maps API [here](https://medium.com/@nixonaugustine5/angular-google-maps-integration-advanced-using-google-drawing-manager-8a6eac6540e1) and [here](https://medium.com/@nixonaugustine5/integrating-angular-with-google-maps-advanced-using-google-drawing-manager-e889e0b25d2a)

Comment: In the end that's how I went forward. It is a very powerful API and has good documentation

Answer (score 16):

You most likely getting errors related with `agm-drawing-manager` component, right? It appears `agm-drawing-manager` directive which is utilized in the [provided demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-polygon) is no longer part of [`angular-google-maps` library](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps) (`1.0.0-beta.5` version) and thatäs the reason why those errors occur.

To enable Google Maps drawing tools the following solution could be considered (adapted from [official example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools)):

**`app.component.html`**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="center.lat" [longitude]="center.lng" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"> 
</agm-map>
```

**`app.component.ts`**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
declare const google: any;

@Component({
  selector: "app-map",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  center: any = {
    lat: 33.5362475,
    lng: -111.9267386
  };

  onMapReady(map) {
    this.initDrawingManager(map);
  }

  initDrawingManager(map: any) {
    const options = {
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        drawingModes: ["polygon"]
      },
      polygonOptions: {
        draggable: true,
        editable: true
      },
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
    };

    const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager(options);
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
  }
}
```

*It could be further improved by introducing, for example, a separate directive for `google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager` class*

**Prerequisites**

In `app.module.ts` don't forget to load `drawing` package via AgmCoreModule module:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: "--YOUR-GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY-GOES-HERE--",
  libraries: ['drawing']
})
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptjb9t) for your reference

Comment: This was exactly my problem!!! Thank you very much!!! No that I can draw the polygon, how can I get the coordinates of each point? I used:
`(mapClick)="onMapClick($event)"` in `<agm-map>` with this function:
`onMapClick(event) {
    console.log(event.coords.lat, event.coords.lng);
  }`
but it is not working

Comment: after `drawingManager.setMap(map);` I used this:
`google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', (event) => {
      // Polygon drawn
      if (event.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
        //this is the coordinate, you can assign it to a variable or pass into another function.
        alert(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());
      }
    });` and I can get the coordinates