# (dragEnd) event doesn't fire in angular 7

Tags: angular, dictionary

i want to save map markers in a list to send their  in a post method using "markerDragEnd" function .the polygon drew ,but the function does not fire . here is my html code

```
        <agm-map [latitude]="center.lat" [longitude]="center.lng" 
               (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)" style="height: 300px;"
               (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)">
         <agm-polygon #mPolygon [paths]="markers" [editable]="true"></agm-polygon>
         <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index" [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lng" 
            [label]="m.label" [markerDraggable]="true" (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(m, $event)">
              <agm-info-window>
                <strong> Info Window content</strong>
              </agm-info-window>

            </agm-marker>
                </agm-map>**strong text**
         markerDragEnd(m, $event: any) {
             console.log('dragEnd', m, $event, this.mPolygon);
          }
```

Comment: I do not know this will differentiate or not , but i have also that error " InvalidValueError: not an Array "

Comment: Can you make a Stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-mszvno

Comment: Doesn't compile for me.

Comment: that is my component output with console  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jdbj.png i want to catch this points of polygan

Comment: Please make a working Stackblitz, otherwise I can't really help you

Comment: Very grateful for your help  ,my browser has an error with stackbitz , i juat want to get coordinates of that polygen with (dragend) event , i found solution to get its from (initial ) function , in this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650666/how-to-draw-polygon-on-angular-google-maps-using-agm-core